# opencsv CSVWriter using utf-8 doesn't seem to work for multiple languages

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, opencsv

I have a very annoying encoding problem using opencsv.
When I export a csv file, I set character type as 'UTF-8'.

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter("D:/test.csv", "UTF-8"));
```

but when I open the csv file with Microsoft Office Excel 2007, it turns out that it has **'UTF-8 BOM'** encoding?

Once I save the file in Notepad and re-open, the file turns back to UTF-8 and all the letters in it appears fine. 
I think I've searched enough, but I haven't found any solution to prevent my file from turning into 'UTF-8 BOM'. any ideas, please?

Comment: Java should not add a BOM on its own, since there also is no `OutputStreamWriter` constructor taking two strings I guess there is something missing from your code. Could the BOM be part of the data you write?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suppose your file has a 'UTF-8 without BOM' encoding. 
You better feed BOM encoding to your file, even though it's not necessary in most cases, but only one obvious exception is when you deal with ms excel.

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(0xef);
os.write(0xbb);
os.write(0xbf);
CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
```

Now your file will be understood by excel as utf-8 csv.

Comment: what is the issue in dealing with ms excel?

Comment: This has been a real nuisance for me for years! Your solution works perfect. Thanks

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Better still, go by the definition of the BOM and use "\uFEFF".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), which returns the correct byte array.

Comment: You can get the correct BOM char from Apache Commons IO ByteOrderMark.UTF_BOM: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/ByteOrderMark.html#UTF_BOM

Comment: Worked like a charm , thanks goodhyun ^^

Answer (score 3):

`UTF-8` and `UTF-8 Signature` (which incorrectly named sometimes as `UTF-8 BOM`) are same encodings, and signature [is used only to distinguish it from any other encodings](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html). Any unicode application should process UTF-8 signature (which is three bytes sequence `EF BB BF`) correctly.

Why Java is specifically adds this signature and how to stop it doing that I don't know.